# How can I calculate network and broadcast using object IP Address and mask IP Address in jQuery?

Tags: networking, broadcast

object IP Address = 192.168.0.101

mask IP Address = 255.255.255.0

network = ?

broadcast = ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var network = calculateNetworkIP("192.168.0.101", "255.255.255.0");

var broadcast = calculateBroadcastIP("192.168.0.101", "255.255.255.0");

function calculateNetworkIP(ipAddress, maskIP){

    var binaryIP = convertIPToBinaryIP(ipAddress);
    var maskBinaryIP = convertIPToBinaryIP(maskIP);

    var binaryNetwork = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < maskBinaryIP.length; j++) {
        binaryNetwork.push(bitwiseAND(binaryIP[j], maskBinaryIP[j]));
    }

    var NetworkIPArr = convertBinaryIPToDecIP(binaryNetwork);

    var NetworkIPStr = "";
    for (var k = 0; k < NetworkIPArr.length; k++) {
        NetworkIPStr += NetworkIPArr[k]+".";
    }
    return NetworkIPStr.slice(0, -1);
}

function calculateBroadcastIP(ipAddress, maskIP){

    var binaryIP = convertIPToBinaryIP(ipAddress);
    var maskBinaryIP = convertIPToBinaryIP(maskIP);
    var invertedMark = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < maskBinaryIP.length; i++) {
        invertedMark.push(invertedBinary(maskBinaryIP[i]));
    }

    var binaryBroadcast = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < maskBinaryIP.length; j++) {
        binaryBroadcast.push(bitwiseOR(binaryIP[j], invertedMark[j]));
    }

    var broadcastIPArr = convertBinaryIPToDecIP(binaryBroadcast);

    var broadcastIPStr = "";
    for (var k = 0; k < broadcastIPArr.length; k++) {
        broadcastIPStr += broadcastIPArr[k]+".";
    }
    return broadcastIPStr.slice(0, -1);
}

function invertedBinary(number){

    var no = number+"";
    var noArr = no.split("");
    var newNo = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < noArr.length; i++){
        if(noArr[i] == "0"){
            newNo += "1";
        }else{
            newNo += "0";
        }
    }
    return newNo;
}

function bitwiseAND(firstBinary, secondBinary){

    var firstArr = [];
    var secondArr = [];
    firstArr = firstBinary.split("");
    secondArr = secondBinary.split("");
    var newAdded = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++){
        if(firstArr[i]+"+"+secondArr[i] == "1+0"){
            newAdded += "0";
        }else if(firstArr[i]+"+"+secondArr[i] == "0+1"){
            newAdded += "0";
        }else if(firstArr[i]+"+"+secondArr[i] == "1+1"){
            newAdded += "1";
        }else if(firstArr[i]+"+"+secondArr[i] == "0+0"){
            newAdded += "0";
        }
    }
    return newAdded;
}

function bitwiseOR(firstBinary, secondBinary){

    var firstArr = [];
    var secondArr = [];
    firstArr = firstBinary.split("");
    secondArr = secondBinary.split("");
    var newAdded = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++){
        if(firstArr[i]+"+"+secondArr[i] == "1+0"){
            newAdded += "1";
        }else if(firstArr[i]+"+"+secondArr[i] == "0+1"){
            newAdded += "1";
        }else if(firstArr[i]+"+"+secondArr[i] == "1+1"){
            newAdded += "1";
        }else if(firstArr[i]+"+"+secondArr[i] == "0+0"){
            newAdded += "0";
        }
    }
    return newAdded;
}

function convertBinaryIPToDecIP(binaryIPArr){

    var broadcastIP = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryIPArr.length; i++) {
        broadcastIP.push(parseInt(parseInt(binaryIPArr[i]), 2));
    }
    return broadcastIP;
}

function convertIPToBinaryIP(ipAddress) {

    var ipArr = ipAddress.split(".");
    var binaryIP = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ipArr.length; i++) {
        var binaryNo = parseInt(ipArr[i]).toString(2);
        if(binaryNo.length == 8){
            binaryIP.push(binaryNo);
        }else{
            var diffNo = 8 - binaryNo.length;
            var createBinary = '';
            for (var j = 0; j < diffNo; j++) {
               createBinary += '0';
            }
            createBinary += binaryNo;
            binaryIP.push(createBinary);
        }
    }
    return binaryIP; 
}
```